# Will be callable bond called or not? Estimating probabilities

Tags: options, callable-bonds

Suppose we have a callable bond in the market. The problem is to find out the probability of being called and the probability of being held until the maturity. My approach for this problem is the following: from the price of the underlying call option derive implied distribution of the bond. This should give insights how market estimates the probability of the bond being executed. Do you think this is correct? What are alternative approaches? Is there any universally accepted methodology for this?

Comment: Problem with option pricing is that it's all within a risk neutral framework. The probabilities usually do not align with real world probabilities. Also, from a single option price, you can't really back out a distribution.

Comment: @AKdemy I didn't mean to back out the implied distribution from a single option. One can use butterfly spread utilizing several call prices to derive the distribution.

Answer (score 2):

[This paper by Philipp Schönbucher](https://dx.doi.org/10.2139/ssrn.240868), also included in his book, explains a binomial tree.

The basic premise is simply that if someone is paying fixed coupon $C$ or floating $I+S$, and at some future call date $t$ the risk free rate becomes $r_t$, and the credit spread becomes $c_t$ such that $r_t+c_t<C$ or $c_t<S$, then the borrower will call the debt and refinance more cheaply.

You can make it a little fancier with behavioral heuristics akin to mortgage prepayment analytics.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the reference, I read the article, but it seems it does not provide an explicit methodology to derive probability of calling the bond.